# How to send email with Spanish characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send an email that has a body with an English version on top and a Spanish translation on the bottom.

```
    string body = "elevación del nivel de los estándares";
```

The spanish part of the body shows up as `elevaci?n del nivel de los est?ndares`

How do I send an email with both english and spanish with the spanish characters showing up correctly?

Comment: Show the code you're using to send the message.  Likely, you'll need to change your encoding.

Comment: Have you set any options to the headers of the mail ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding

Comment: I haven't set any options to the headers or changed encoding.  Do you have any code examples for that?  I need to display english and spanish in the same email.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`MailMessage.BodyEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding.aspx) property, you'll note the following:

> The default character set is "us-ascii".

Try changing your encoding before sending:

```
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

(I'm assuming you're sending using a [`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx).  If you're using [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) directly, I would recommend switching to using the `MailMessage` class and passing instances of that to your `SmtpClient`.)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, that was a simple fix.  I'm trying to accept your answer but it's making me wait 5 minutes.  Thanks

Comment: +1 for good answer and telepathic power in finding what OP used to send message.