# Special characters in PHP mail

Tags: php, forms, email, character

I am having trouble with my PHP mail form, and the use of danish letters Æ,Ø and Å. They appear as rubbish when recieved by email.

I tried the function find and replace, but I simply cannot get it to work.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$errors = array();
$navn = $_POST ['navn'];
$adresse = $_POST ['adresse'];
$postby = $_POST ['postby'];
$telefon = $_POST ['telefon'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];
if (empty($navn) === true || empty($adresse) === true || empty($postby) === true ||        empty($telefon) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Du skal skrive i alle felter!';
} else {

}
if (empty($errors) === true) {

}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    mail('mymail.dk', 'Kontakt fra mydomain.dk', "Navn: " . $_POST["navn"] . "\nAdresse: " . $_POST["adresse"] . "\nPost nr. & By: " . $_POST["postby"] . "\nTelefon: " . $_POST["telefon"] . "\nEmail: " . $_POST["email"] . "\nBesked: " . $_POST["message"], 'From: ' . 'mydomain.dk');
    header('Location: tak-for-din-mail.php');
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a character encoding issue. You should be able to find more info here [PHP E-Mail Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding).

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I struggle to find out how to incorporate the headers in my own code, because I have tried dozens of PHP mail methods and this is the only one that works.

Comment: You should just be able to add a headers parameter to your current mail() call. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Do the characters appear as rubbish on all mail clients or just some?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the utf8 charset to the additional parameters of the mail() method.
 Read the manual.

Comment: Well I have tried that, adding content-type etc.. after , in my mail () method, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a header in the PHP file something like this

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you. Should this be placed under header('Location: tak-for-din-mail.php');?

Comment: I don't think the location matters. Though for all purposes the content type header generally tends to be right at the top of the file.