# I receive strange text without accents from a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm making a form with the POST method on a .PHP file but when I receive the e-mail it has lot of strange characters that should be letters with accents.

It looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mail'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "alala@alala.com";

    $email_subject = "lalala";


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['nome']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mail']) ||
        !isset($_POST['site']) ||
        !isset($_POST['autorizacao']) ||
        !isset($_POST['banca']) ||
        !isset($_POST['descricao']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mesa'])) {
        died('');       
    }

    $nome = $_POST['nome']; // required
    $mail = $_POST['mail']; // required
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone']; // required
    $site = $_POST['site']; // required
    $autorizacao = $_POST['autorizacao']; // required
    $banca = $_POST['banca']; // required
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao']; // required
    $mesa = $_POST['mesa']; // required
    $sugestoes = $_POST['sugestoes']; // required

    $email_message = "Inscrição para a Showroom:.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Nome: ".clean_string($nome)."\n";
    $email_message .= "E-mail: ".clean_string($mail)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($telefone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($site)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($autorizacao)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($banca)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($descricao)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($mesa)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($sugestoes)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a content-type header. I advice you to start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add encoding to `$headers`:

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```