# Character set in PHP, mySQL and emails

Tags: php, mysql, email, character-encoding

Character sets are driving me round the bend!

My database is utf8_general_ci and the tables within it are utf8_unicode_ci.
All my PHP pages have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in the head.

When I type a euro symbol (€) in the PHP page and input it to the database it appears in phpMyAdmin as â‚¬
When I use a PHP page to copy it from the database, it reappears as €

So far so good, but when I write am html email using PHP, no matter what I do it comes out in the email as â‚¬
I've tried specifying the character set in the html email but it doesn't work. Probably because email clients take their character set from the mail server and not the headers.
I've also got issues with accented letters and the like, but they are being written into the text so I could overcome them by using é for é, and so on. Messy, but not impossible.

Surely there's a better way!

**MY SOLUTION (SORT OF)**

Thanks to all who contributed. I have tried all ways to specify the character set to utf-8 (in the mail headers, in the html head, and both) but the message still arrives in iso. So it seems the information I got from elsewhere was right: character set is defined by the server.

I have had to settle for typing things like é each time I want é into the fixed text, which is cumbersome but at least it works.

For the euro symbol, I have wrapped the variable in the htmlentities function. It works, but I will have to remember to do it with any other variables taken from the database if I encounter similar problems in similar files. It would have been easier to wrap the function around the entire html body but that doesn't work, presumably because it does funny things with the .

Comment: how do you send emails in php? usally you can set the charset for the mail in the body

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding in your text editor. Crazy things can happen if this is wrong!

For MySQL, see [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

Emails actually get their character set from the `Content-Type` header, not from the email server. Make sure you set this header to an appropriate value, such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding).

And keep in mind that for HTML, you can use `$encoded = htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' )` so that [all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the correct answer for you is just setting utf-8 charset for the e-mail:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($from_name)."?= <".$from_a.">\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: $reply\r\n";  
$headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($to, $s, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the email source in your client (ctrl+u in thunderbird). You will see a Content-Type header. This should be something like:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If your email contains multiple parts your need to add that header to html part.

Header values need to be encoded separately (each line).

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?...?=
```

For the html content you can just use htmlentities() but this will not work for the headers or a text email.