# PHP Email with Spanish accents incorrectly showing

Tags: php, email

My website is salonesvip.cl

The website itself shows spanish accents perfectly, no problems there.
In the contact form itself, it shows spanish accents.
The email that is generated and arrives to me once they hit send... that's the problem.

My only guess is that its the PHP, as the website shows them no problem.

I've spent hours trying to find the solution, and I really can't find a fix.

I attach the php, hoping someone knows what's the problem... and if you need any more info, please tell me.

Thanks

mailer.php

```
<?php
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $salon = $_POST["salon"];
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $celu = trim($_POST["celu"]);
    $creditCard = trim($_POST["creditCard"]);
    $subjectwa = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR empty($celu) OR empty($creditCard) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! No se puede enviar el formulario, verifica los campos.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "XXX@salonesvip.cl";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web.  Su nombre es: $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Salon: $salon\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Celular: $celu\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Credit Card: $creditCard\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Subject: $subjectwa\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Gracias! Su mensaje ha sido enviado.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! No se puede enviar el formulario, verifica los campos.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Oops! No se puede enviar el formulario, verifica los campos.";
}
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your encoding in email header 
(I don't know which is correct for spanish but you propably do ;-)

This is example for your code and UTF-8:

```
$email_headers  = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
$email_headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: You should also have a "\r\n" attached  at the first line.

Comment: @violator667  Perfect.  Man, 2 hours wasted for a line of code.  Thank you so much... perfect answer!

Comment: @violator667  Ok, so something funky just happened.  I am getting emails showing the correct Spanish accents, but now all the text is in one continuous line. Any ideas?  I used to get name: xxx <br/> Salon xxx <br/>, etc....   Now  I get name salon email, cel, etc AND message in a continuous line.  Let me know

Comment: You have to format your email body like a html page.

Comment: Sorry, to be a pain.  :(     @violator667  Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Something like : `<html><head></head><body><h1>Email</h1><p>paragraph</p><p>second paragraph</p></body></html>` ;-)

Comment: @violator667  Thanks, but I figured it out... and the problem was the "\r\n".  I swapped that our for <br>... things swimming now.  Thanks again!!