# How do I make my php form accept foreign language characters?

Tags: php, utf-8, outlook, character

I have created a php form that needs to accept foreign characters (such as Traditional Chinese and Vietnamese). This is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "Tristar Registration Request";
$EmailTo = "sbehringer@parsec-corp.com";
$Subject = "Tristar Registration Request";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Company']));
$Address = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Address']));
$Contact = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Contact']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$headers .= 'To: Tristar <info@ghstag.com>' . "\r\n";

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $Company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $Address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Contact: ";
$Body .= $Contact;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

//convert invalid strings
$newstring = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8/IGNORE', $Body);

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=registerthanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

When I submit a test to Gmail the special characters come through no problem, but when the email goes through Outlook it appears as gibberish. Am I missing some UTF-8 encoding or is it a special setting without Outlook that I need to adjust to accept foreign characters. Any help would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP E-Mail Encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8' to your email headers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use e.g. "Swiftmailer", otherwise you will still have problems with (utf-8) mail-subject and many other mail-functionality. :/