# Make form that sends email

Tags: php, html, email

I have this web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Send Email</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="myEmail" placeholder="Имейл"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="recieverEmail" placeholder="Получател"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Предмет"/><br>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" placeholder="Съобщение"></textarea><br>

            <input type="submit" name="button" value="send"/>
        </form>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['button'])){

                $sender = $_GET['myEmail'];
                $reciever = $_GET['recieverEmail'];
                $subject = $_GET['subject'];
                $message = $_GET['message'];
                $headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";

                mail($reciever, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get data from the html form. I need a way to set the encoding of the email to UTF-8 because when I want to send email in Bulgarian, it is not translating into Bulgarian. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` method here.

Comment: To set mail encoding please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265627/2438241.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Add one more header attribute in your code like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['button'])){
    $sender = $_GET['myEmail'];
    $reciever = $_GET['recieverEmail'];
    $subject = $_GET['subject'];
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    $headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";  //check this header attribute. It will append to the `From` header.
    mail($reciever, $subject, $message, $headers, $encoding);
}
```

Comment: how can I change the from attribute because the code doesn't send the email

Comment: You said email is being sent but its not in `Bulgarian` language.

Comment: No, I didn't receive the email

Comment: Before it was sending, but not in Bulgarian, yes