# How to change php code to solve character coding issue?

Tags: php, email, utf-8

I wrote this php email sender code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$recaptcha_secret = "xy";
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

if($response["success"] === true){
    $mailTo = "info@domain.hu";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "Feladó: ".$name."\nTelefonszám: ".$phone."\nCég: ".$company."\nWeboldal: ".$website."\n\nÜzenet: ".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
header("Location: feedback/koszonjuk");
    
    
}else{
    header("Location: feedback/error");
}

}

?>`
```

It sends email to my server side email address after someone fill out my form on my website with recaptcha.

I want to have the emails in UTF-8 character coding, but I can not see the issue. These characters are mismanaged in the emails from the form: öüóőúéá

The HTML page where the form is located is set to UTF-8.
The HTML form code:

```
<form action="ajanlatkeres.php" method="post" class="ajanlatkeres-form" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <h2>Általános adatok</h2>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Teljes név*" class="feedback-input" required>
                        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail*" class="feedback-input" required>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefonszám*" class="feedback-input" required>
                    <h2>Vállalkozás adatai</h2>
                        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Márkanév" class="feedback-input">
                        <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Weboldal" class="feedback-input">
                    
                    <h2>Üzenet</h2>
                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Ajánlatkérés">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Írj pár sort projektedről*" class="feedback-input" required></textarea>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" id="rcaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="xy"></div>
                        <br/>
                        <button id="submit_form" class="contactbutton" type="submit" name="submit">Küldés</button>
                    </form>
```

What can cause this issue? Is it in my php code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP E-Mail Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265579/php-e-mail-encoding)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. On that link I found this: Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8 -> that seemed like a good idea as my emails are text emails, but it help nothing. I try to add this code in the beginning of my php or in the header sender part but nothing.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265627/12763954) (just replace `text/html` with `text/plain`).

Comment: Check the PHP manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, especially the section _Example #5 Sending HTML email_.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I tried to implement these, but nothing helped unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `content-type and character encoding` in headers

```
$headers = "From: " . $mailFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Comment: Olivier suggested earlier that the asker look at this potential solution which was already available on Stack Overflow. [PHP E-Mail Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265627/2943403) Please read the comments and and other answers before posting an answer.  We don't want to bloat Stack Overflow with redundant advice.  This answer adds no new value to Stack Overflow.